# Python: Can a function return an array and a variable?

Tags: python, arrays, function

Is there a simple way to get a function to return a np.array and a variable?

eg:

```
my_array = np.zeros(3)
my_variable = 0.

def my_function():
    my_array = np.array([1.,2.,3.])
    my_variable = 99.
    return my_array,my_variable

my_function()
```

so that the values calculated in the function can be used later in the code? The above ignores the values calculated in the function.

I tried returning a tuple {my_array, my_variable} but got the unhashable type message for np.array

DN

Comment: Tuples are written with parentheses — `()` — not braces — `{}`.

Comment: If you want to return a tuple, it should be `(my_array, my_variable)`. Using curly brackets is returning `dict`, which requires the element to be hashable, in this case, `list` is not.

Comment: @justhalf: Using curly braces without colons builds a `set`, not a `dict`.

Comment: The code currently shown above has no errors, you're just not storing the result anywhere.

Comment: @abamert: oops, sorry

Comment: @abarnert Correct. And since a set requires each item to be distinct, it requires hashable items to be added, which is why he got the unhashable type error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not ignoring the values returned, you aren't assigning them to variables.

```
my_array, my_variable = my_function()
```

Comment: `my_array, my_variable` _is_ a tuple. It's the commas that make tuples, not the parens. The parens are only necessary in certain places for disambiguation, like inside a function call. (They're almost always harmless, and often make things more readable, even when they're not necessary—just about the only place in Python, outside of complex algebraic expressions, where unnecessary parens are often worth typing anyway.)

Comment: The 'return tuple' approach worked, and was needed, as the array was much larger than the size=3 example.  Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 20):

Your function is correct. When you write `return my_array,my_variable`, your function is actually returning a tuple `(my_array, my_variable)`.

You can first assign the return value of `my_function()` to a variable, which would be this tuple I describe:

```
result = my_function()
```

Next, since you know how many items are in the tuple ahead of time, you can [*unpack the tuple*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) into two distinct values:

```
result_array, result_variable = result
```

Or you can do it in one line:

```
result_array, result_variable = my_function()
```

---

**Other notes related to returning tuples, and tuple unpacking:**

I sometimes keep the two steps separate, if my function can return `None` in a non-exceptional failure or empty case:

```
result = my_function()
if result == None:
    print 'No results'
    return
a,b = result
# ...
```

Instead of unpacking, alternatively you can access specified items from the tuple, using their index:

```
result = my_function()
result_array = result[0]
result_variable = result[1]
```

If for whatever reason you have a 1-item tuple:

```
return (my_variable,)
```

You can unpack it with the same (slightly awkward) one-comma syntax:

```
my_variable, = my_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

easy answer

```
my_array, my_variable = my_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

After the definition of my_function, use my_function = np.vectorize(my_function).
For example,

```
def jinc(x):
    if x == 0.0:
        return 1
    return 2*j1(x)/x

jinc = np.vectorize(jinc)
```

Comment: This example allows x and returned values are numpy array.